# C# - Access denied al utilizar AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Tags: c#, update

He creado una aplicación que tiene un sistema de actualización, algo poco convencional:

esta aplicación se instala y se ejecuta desde:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Application test
```

el ejecutable se llama:

```
searchdata.exe
```

pero en algún momento se me ocurrió la gran idea de hacer un sistema de actualización que ejecuta los siguientes pasos:

1. Haga clic en el botón de actualización: compruebe si existe el ejecutable `update.exe`.

- si existe, ejecútelo inmediatamente y cierre `searchdata.exe`.
- no existe: descargue `update.dat` de una URL y cambie el nombre a update.exe.

2. Este es el script de la barra de progreso y descarga:

```cs
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadFileWithProgress("http://test.pro/installer/update.dat", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "update.exe", ProgressBar1, Label4);
        }

        private void DownloadFileWithProgress(string DownloadLink, string TargetPath, ProgressBar Progress, Label LabelProgress)
        {
            int bytesProcessed = 0;
            Stream remoteStream = null;
            Stream localStream = null;
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
                double TotalBytesToReceive = 0;
                var SizewebRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(DownloadLink));
                SizewebRequest.Method = "HEAD";
                using (var WebResponse = SizewebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    var fileSize = WebResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Length");
                    TotalBytesToReceive = Convert.ToDouble(fileSize);
                }
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    string filePath = TargetPath;
                    localStream = File.Create(filePath); // Aquí mero es el error
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                        double bytesIn = double.Parse(bytesProcessed.ToString());
                        double percentage = bytesIn / TotalBytesToReceive * 100;
                        percentage = Math.Round(percentage, 0);
                        if (Progress.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            Progress.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                            {
                                Progress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                            }));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Progress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                        }
                        if (LabelProgress.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            LabelProgress.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                            {
                                LabelProgress.Text = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()) + "%";
                            }));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LabelProgress.Text = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()).ToString() + "%";
                        }
                    }
                    while (bytesRead > 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(response.StatusDescription, "Respuesta del Servidor");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error en DownloadFileWithProgress" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                    response.Close();
                if (remoteStream != null)
                    remoteStream.Close();
                if (localStream != null)
                    localStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

3. el problema es que estoy ejecutando con privilegios normales, **no quiero tener que usar privilegios administrativos**, pero la ejecución me da un error de acceso denegado al intentar escribir el archivo en el directorio de la aplicación.

Comment: *el problema es que estoy ejecutando con privilegios normales, no quiero tener que usar privilegios administrativos, pero la ejecución me da un error de acceso denegado al intentar escribir el archivo en el directorio de la aplicación.* -> Esa es, de hecho, una de las mejores medidas de seguridad de windows :) Y creo que no hay forma de saltársela si no tienes permisos de administrador en algún momento

Comment: @Benito-B busco alternativas... pro eso hago la obsevacion de que otra manera se puede hacer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay una solución, especifica hasta hoy 14/04/2021.
Para Sistema Operativos Windows la carpetas

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\
C:\Program Files\
```

están bloqueada y solo tienen acceso los instaladores y la ejecución de software con privilegios elevados, por temas de seguridad no hay manera y es preferible no tratar de evitar este parametrización del S.O.

La solución Alterna tiene que ver con el uso de `ClickOnce` de Microsoft para el soporte de actualizaciones o el uso de `AppData` en la arquitectura y diseño del software en donde, el programa principal es un `Launcher` que apunta a los datos y ejecutables en `AppData`.

Documentación relacionada:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data

https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/variables-entorno-que-sirven-como-podemos-editarlas-windows-linux

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7946155/4717133

Como no soy un experto estoy buscando algún tutorial o documentación oficial para apoyarme en la refactorización de la aplicación.